# Targeting a child object in JSON file when item is in view is clicked - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Ok, so my problem is that I have the following set up in my view:

```
<a class="like" ng-tap="likeClicked()"><span>{{isLiked}}</span></a>
```

Also, I have another crucial view element:

```
<span class="like-count" ng-tap="viewLikes()" ng-init="likeCount=feed.likes.length"{{likeCount}}</span>
```

Then is my controller, I have the following code:

```
$scope.likeClicked = function () {

    console.log($scope.feeds);

    if (!hasLiked) {
      hasLiked = true;
      $scope.isLiked = 'Unlike';
    } else {
      hasLiked = false;
      $scope.isLiked = 'Like';         
    }
  };
```

And, finally, some dummy JSON:

```
  {
    "id":5,
    "title":"Feed 1",
    "createdby":1,
    "typeId":2,
    "content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,",
    "createdon":"2013-03-21 14:53:35",
    "editedon":"2013-03-21 14:53:35",
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "createdby": 5,
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,",
        "createdon":"2013-03-21 14:53:35"
      }
    ],
    "likes": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "createdby": 4,
        "createdon":"2013-03-21 14:53:35"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "createdby": 2,
        "createdon":"2013-03-21 14:53:35"
      }
    ]
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve, is that when the user taps `likeClicked`, the 'like' is liked (though this bit works). Then once liked I need to get the `.length`of the array in the JSON child associated to that feed item. The problem comes that I can use the console log to return the objects in the console using `console.log($scope.feeds);`, however, if I use `console.log($scope.feeds.likes);`, this returns undefined, even though it is an available object in the array and in the `$scope` of the clicked element.

What I don't want to do is specify a specific child of the JSON, `console.log($scope.feeds[3});` for example, because it would be better if I could dynamically set the child based on the item in the `ng-repeat` that is clicked.

Any Angular bad-asses out there, please help!

Thanks,

JP

Comment: I tried to simulate the error you are getting but console.log($scope.feeds.likes) works fine, you can see it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LUKmdwESIiehtIyJImH). It would be easier if you setup a plunker/fiddle/jsbin with more code.

Comment: I can't get that Plunker to work Bertrand.

Comment: I have made a Plunker here, though mine also doesn't work!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ft1YgUsXCnFxfyr5ob8r

Comment: There was a problem with the JSON object, I am not sure how your data is supposed to be but I imagine it is an array with several feed objects like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6DUBGKE9GyEK26UIabv?p=preview), right?

Comment: Ok, I have it working! http://plnkr.co/edit/IGxw8P7YT85jVRMnOVgU - Now, my issue is targeting one instance of 'like' in a feed, rather than all of them? Then also, how to do this in general: How to target the individual instances of 'feed in feeds', in my example, without changing the whole $scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target individual instances of feeds you can use the propertie $index that ng-repeat exposes and pass it to likeClicked() method.

```
<article ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
    <h3>{{feed.createdby}}</h3>
    <p>{{feed.content}}</p>
    <button ng-click="likeClicked($index)">{{isLiked}}</button>
</article>
```

Knowing the index you could keep track of each feed/like individually, to give you an example I created an object (isLiked) to hold this data.

To change the button's text I'd use a filter that works based on the values stored in the isLike object.

Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OJmSFIppizpTtUiOcqxD?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. That is a good way to go as I need the $index to manipulate a like count also!